# Split colour background (CSS & HTML)

Tags: html, css, background

Is there a way for me to have a split colour background, so I have left half of the page black, right half white.

Usually I will have the `<header>` and `<footer>` which will be full width at top and bottom of the page and inside, a wrapper, to centre the content of those elements so the content isn't full width of the entire `body`.

Now when it comes to the actual content where posts and side navigation etc could be, I want one side to be white and one side to be light grey.

I know I can create two columns inside a centred `wrapper` floated left with different background colours, but that would still leave the `background` colour showing on either side of the `wrapper`.

I hope someone understands what I'm talking about, I have no idea how to explain it or what to search.

I will make a quick picture in paint and attach to this post soon,

many thanks!

**Edit:** [Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n50K.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```css
header, footer{
  background-color: #ff3399;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
.container{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.bg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  height: 3000px;
}
.bgwhite{
  background-color: white;
  width: 50%;
  left: 0;
}
.bggray{
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 50%;
  right: 0;
}
.wrapper{
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>This is header</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="bg bgwhite"></div>
  <div class="bg bggray"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content. This is website content.</p>
  </div>
<footer>This is footer</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do:

HTML

```
<div id="content"></div>
<div id="background"></div>
```

CSS

```
#background {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    z-index: 1;
}

#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So if I add a content wrapper it will display on top of these div elements, directly underneath the header, because of the div positions?

I will test it out when I get home!